# in python ,if i edit this: type("myclass", (foo,), {"bar()", barbar}, how can i access the attribute "bar()"

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
>>> FooChild = type("FooChild", (Foo,), {"echobar()":echo_bar})
>>> FooChild().echobar()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#214>", line 1, in <module>
    FooChild().echobar()
AttributeError: 'FooChild' object has no attribute 'echobar'
>>> FooChild().echobar

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#215>", line 1, in <module>
    FooChild().echobar
AttributeError: 'FooChild' object has no attribute 'echobar'
>>> hasattr(FooChild, "echobar()")
True
>>> FooChild().echobar()()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#217>", line 1, in <module>
    FooChild().echobar()()
AttributeError: 'FooChild' object has no attribute 'echobar'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echobar()` is an [**invalid identifier**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) in python, so you can't access it directly i.e using the dot syntax:

```
>>> FooChild = type("FooChild", (Foo,), {"echobar()":10})
```

Use `__dict__` or `getattr`:

```
>>> FooChild.__dict__['echobar()']
10
>>> getattr(FooChild, 'echobar()')
10
```

If you want to use it as an attribute then simply get rid of the parenthesis:

```
>>> FooChild = type("FooChild", (Foo,), {"echobar":10})
>>> FooChild.echobar
10
```

If you want to use it as a method, then:

```
>>> def echobar(self):return 10

>>> FooChild = type("FooChild", (Foo,), {'echobar':echobar})
>>> FooChild().echobar()
10
```

Comment: thx, your answer is perfect. the last two way i used to know. my english is poor...

Answer (score 3):

Remove those parentheses:

```
FooChild = type("FooChild", (Foo,), {"echobar":echo_bar})
```

The name of a function is without the parentheses.  Appending them means to *call* the function.  Without the parentheses you have a reference on the function itself (e. g. for passing a function to things like `sort` or `map`).

Comment: thx.~ i just want to konw how to get that attri with parentheses.

Comment: The parentheses are an operator appended to the function to call it.  It is like calling `echo_bar.__call__()`.  The entity "the attri wih parentheses" does not exist, it is an expression.  Its value is the result of the call of the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you pretend to have fancy function with name `echobar()` in you class, only mean of accessing it is `getattr`:

```
class Foo(object):pass
echo_bar =lambda *a: 'bar'
FooChild = type("FooChild", (Foo,), {"echobar()":echo_bar})
print getattr(FooChild(), 'echobar()')()
# bar
```